# How to use skip argument in fread() to read rows before a specific string?

Tags: r, data.table

I have the following data example in a *.txt file:

```
structure(c("class1", "class2", NA, "tot", NA, "x", "y", NA, 
"z", "5", "10", NA, "15", NA, "2", "7", NA, "4"), dim = c(9L, 
2L), dimnames = list(NULL, c("col1", "col2")))
```

How could I read this *.txt file with `fread()` using skip or another argument to read rows before a specific string?

Desired output:

```
      col1     col2
 [1,] "class1" "5" 
 [2,] "class2" "10"
 [3,] NA       NA  
 [4,] "tot"    "15"
```

In this code above I would like to read rows above the string `tot` in the variable `class1`.

Thanks

Comment: When you have a question about how to get `fread` to provide your expected results, it really helps when you have a representative _raw file_, not just the post-`fread` results.

Comment: How important is it to have this solution work inside `fread` rather than after? It would be much simpler to `fread` the whole file and then pull the values you want from the resulting data.table. This would only seem to be a bad idea if (a) the files are massive and you want to avoid the overhead of reading unnecessary data or (b) the files are poorly formed below that point and it messes up the read.

Comment: Do you have any idea where the string is located? If it could be anywhere, you'll need to run something to figure out what row that string appears before you read the data. There's no "stop early" option for `fread()`. What OS are you running? `fread()` can read from pipes so you could use a unix tool to trim the input stream when it encounters a certain character if you are on linux or mac or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

```
raw <- readLines("test.txt")
fread(text = raw, nrows = grep("tot", raw) - 1, header = T)
```

**output**

```
     col1 col2
1: class1    5
2: class2   10
3:   <NA>   NA
4:    tot   15
```

**test.txt**

```
col1 col2
class1 5
class2 10
NA NA  
tot 15
NA NA  
x 2
y 7
NA NA  
z 4
```